# Regular Expression to select all sentences Except one sentence with specific word

Tags: regex, inverse, sentence

I want to select all sentences which do not includes **"Bull & Cat"** word.

**This is a Dog. This is  Cat. This is a Bull. This is a Cow**

```
((?<=^)|(?<=\.))\s*(?![^.]*Bull).*?(?:\.|$)((?<=$)|(?<=\.))
```

This regex selects sentences except one that contain **Bull**, but I need to select all sentences other than contains **Bull & Cat**.

Edit the above regex. So, i can select all sentences except those who contains Bull & Cat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

`((?<=^)|(?<=\.))\s*(?![^.]*Bull).*?(?:\.|$)((?<=$)|(?<=\.))`

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/Y3gerF/1

The above regex will include the ending dots at the end of each sentence inside the match. If you don't mind not getting those dots, you can simplify a little bit to:

`((?<=^)|(?<=\.))\s*(?![^.]*Bull).*?((?=$)|(?=\.))`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wzq4Sr/1

Comment: and what if I want to exclude sentences with Bull & Cat both words